# Setting a drawable icon isn't working with me on android

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

I'm using the function setCompoundDrawablesRelativewithIntrinsicBounds but nothing I do to fix this seems to work.

My MainActivity code:

```
 private fun setIcons() {

        val view = findViewById(R.id.Head) as? TextView

        view?.setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.therm, 0, 0, 0)

    }
```

I call this function in the onCreate

My XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/cardview_default_elevation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Head"
                android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
                android:text="Heading"
                android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            </TextView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Desc"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
                android:textAlignment="textEnd"
                android:text="Description"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            </TextView>

        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
view?.setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(AppCompatResources.getDrawable(view!!.context, R.drawable.therm), null, null, null)
```